# I have 2 forms on this page one, if i only have one it works fine as soon as i add the 2nd it doesnt work?

Tags: php

How am i able to have two form submissions on the one page?
I have 2 forms on this page one, if i only have one it works fine as soon as i add the 2nd it doesnt work? 
Is it possible or do have have to link out to another page

site is http://www.vestedutility.com.au/join_vested_utility.php

```
 <?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $FNAME= trim($_POST["FNAME"]);
    $LNAME = trim($_POST["LNAME"]);
    $CNAME = trim($_POST["CNAME"]);

    $EMAIL= trim($_POST["EMAIL"]);
    $MMERGE4 = trim($_POST["MMERGE4"]);
    $MMERGE5 = trim($_POST["MMERGE5"]);
      $MMERGE3addr1 = trim($_POST["MMERGE3addr1"]);
      $MMERGE3city= trim($_POST["MMERGE3city"]);
      $MMERGE3state = trim($_POST["MMERGE3state"]);
      $MMERGE3zip = trim($_POST["MMERGE3zip"]);
    $MMERGE3country = trim($_POST["MMERGE3country"]);
    $ecew= trim($_POST["ecew"]);


    if ($LNAME == "" OR $EMAIL== ""OR $MMERGE4== ""OR $MMERGE4== "" OR $MMERGE6== "") {
       $error_message = "You must specify a value for name, email address, phone number, post code and message.";

    }
if (!isset($error_message)) { 
    foreach( $_POST as $value ){
        if( stripos($value,'Content-Type:') !== FALSE ){
            echo "There was a problem with the information you entered.";    
            exit;
        }
    }
}    

    if (!isset($error_message) && $_POST["address"] != "") {
        $error_message = "Your form submission has an error.";

    }

    require_once("inc/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

   if (!isset($error_message) && !$mail->ValidateAddress($EMAIL)){
        $error_message = "You must specify a valid email address.";

    }
if (!isset($error_message)){ 
    $email_body = "";
    $email_body = $email_body . "First Name: " . $FNAME . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "Last Name: " . $LNAME . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "Compnay Name: " . $CNAME . "<br>";

    $email_body = $email_body . "Email: " . $EMAIL . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "Phone: " . $MMERGE4 . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "Mobile: " . $MMERGE5 . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "Address: " . $MMERGE3addr1 . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "City: " . $MMERGE3city . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "State: " . $MMERGE3state . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "Post code: " . $MMERGE3zip . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "Country: " . $MMERGE3country . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "EC OR EW number: " . $ECEW;

    $mail->SetFrom($EMAIL, $FNAME, LNAME);
    $address = "james@vestedutility.com";
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "test");
    $mail->Subject    = " VESTED UTILITY JOB MAIL | " . $LNAME;
    $mail->MsgHTML($email_body);

    if($mail->Send()) {
        header("Location: $location?status=thanks");
    exit;
    } else {
      $error_message =  "There was a problem sending the email: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
      exit;
    }


}    
}
     ?>





<?php 
$pageTitle = "Join Vested Utility Electricians";
$section = "join vested utility";
$slogan =   'Find Electrical work in Perth';
include('inc/header.php');
?>


<body> 

<section class="joinvu">
  <div class="section page1">   
     <h5>Join Vested Utility<text class="r">&reg</text> to get quality <br>
       Electrical job leads in your location</h5>

      <p id="p_landing">
      Vested Utility<text class="r">&reg</text> was created by Electricians who have battled large scale 
contractors & franchises and felt the pressure of trying to find work during 
slow periods. Our solution was to create a system based lead generation 
platform, providing affordable marketing to small business without dreaded 
franchise obligations. 
      </p>
         <div class="wrapper" id="why">       

    <div class="why">
    <ul class="reasons">
        <li class="r1">Looking for work in Perth metropolitian?</li>
        <li class="r2">Need help booking and planning jobs?</li>
        <li class="r3">Starting an Electrical business?</li>

        <li class="vusupport">Vested Utility is here to help. 
         </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

        </div>

    </div>

  <div class="section page">







                        <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup" class="joinform">
<form action="electrical_work_perth.php" method="post" class="indexform" class="elecform">
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <h2 id="contactus"> Enquire now by entering your details below.</h2>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    <input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($FNAME)) {echo htmlspecialchars($FNAME); } ?>" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME" placeholder="First Name" required>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    <input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($LNAME)) {echo htmlspecialchars($LNAME); } ?>" name="LNAME" class="required" id="mce-LNAME" placeholder="Last Name" required>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    <input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($CNAME)) {echo htmlspecialchars($CNAME); } ?>" name="CNAME" class="required" id="mce-CNAME" placeholder="Company Name" required>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    <input type="email" value="<?php if (isset($EMAIL)) {echo htmlspecialchars($EMAIL); } ?>" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email Address" required>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    <input type="text" name="MMERGE4" class="required" value="<?php if (isset($MMERGE4)) {echo specialcharacter($MMERGE4); } ?>" id="mce-MMERGE4" placeholder="Phone number" required>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
    <input type="text" name="MMERGE5" class="" value="" id="mce-MMERGE5" placeholder="Mobile number">
</div>
<div class="mc-address-group">
    <div class="mc-field-group">
    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        <input type="text" value="" maxlength="140" name="MMERGE3addr1" id="mce-MMERGE3-addr1" class="required" placeholder="Address">
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
        <input type="text" value="" maxlength="40" name="MMERGE3city" id="mce-MMERGE3-city" class="required" placeholder="City">
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="20" name="MMERGE3state" id="mce-MMERGE3-state" class="required" placeholder="State" >
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
        <input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($MMERGE3zip)) {echo htmlspecialchars($MMERGE3zip); } ?>" maxlength="10" name="MMERGE3zip" id="mce-MMERGE3-zip" class="required" placeholder="Post Code" >
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
        <select name="MMERGE3country" id="mce-MMERGE3-country" class="required"><option value="">Select a country</option><option value="Australia" selected>Australia</option></select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    <input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($ecew)) {echo htmlspecialchars($ecew); } ?>" name="ecew" class="required" id="mce-ecew" placeholder="EC or EW Number" required>
</div>
    <table id="mainform">
            <tr style="display: none;">
                            <th>
                                <label for="address">Address</label>
                            </th>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
                                <p>Humans (and frogs): please leave this field blank.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
        </table>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_f07378b089dcb03e4f7d873e9_c95eea1049" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Send" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="submit"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->

   </section>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/click-popup-window/jquery.popup.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/click-popup-window/demo/css/jquery.popup.css" type="text/css">

    <div id="wrapper_download">



       <a name="download_information_pdf">
       <p class="extra">       </p> 
      <div class="Download_information_pdf">
      <?php if (isset($_GET["status"]) AND $_GET["status"] == "thanks") { ?>
                <p id="thanks">
                <a href="index.php">
                Thank you for submitting your details, please click here to start the download.</a>
               </p>
            <?php } else { ?> 

        <p><a href="#" class="js__p_start"> Download information PDF</br>
        </a> </p>
        <div class="p_anch">

</div>
</a>



<div class="p_body js__p_body js__fadeout"></div>

<div class="popup js__popup js__slide_top">

<a href="#" class="p_close js__p_close" title="Close"></a>

<div class="p_content">




  <section id="page-one">




   <div class="section page2">

        <div class="wrapper">       



              <div id="mc_embed_signup" class="joinform">
<form action="join_vested_utility.php" method="post" class="indexform" class="elecform">
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <h2 id="contactus"> Enquire now by entering your details below.</h2>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    <input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($FNAME)) {echo htmlspecialchars($FNAME); } ?>" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME" placeholder="First Name" required>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    <input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($LNAME)) {echo htmlspecialchars($LNAME); } ?>" name="LNAME" class="required" id="mce-LNAME" placeholder="Last Name" required>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    <input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($CNAME)) {echo htmlspecialchars($CNAME); } ?>" name="CNAME" class="required" id="mce-CNAME" placeholder="Company Name" required>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    <input type="email" value="<?php if (isset($EMAIL)) {echo htmlspecialchars($EMAIL); } ?>" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email Address" required>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    <input type="text" name="MMERGE4" class="required" value="<?php if (isset($MMERGE4)) {echo specialcharacter($MMERGE4); } ?>" id="mce-MMERGE4" placeholder="Phone number" required>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
    <input type="text" name="MMERGE5" class="" value="" id="mce-MMERGE5" placeholder="Mobile number">
</div>
<div class="mc-address-group">
    <div class="mc-field-group">
    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        <input type="text" value="" maxlength="140" name="MMERGE3addr1" id="mce-MMERGE3-addr1" class="required" placeholder="Address">
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
        <input type="text" value="" maxlength="40" name="MMERGE3city" id="mce-MMERGE3-city" class="required" placeholder="City">
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="20" name="MMERGE3state" id="mce-MMERGE3-state" class="required" placeholder="State" >
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
        <input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($MMERGE3zip)) {echo htmlspecialchars($MMERGE3zip); } ?>" maxlength="10" name="MMERGE3zip" id="mce-MMERGE3-zip" class="required" placeholder="Post Code" >
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
        <select name="MMERGE3country" id="mce-MMERGE3-country" class="required"><option value="">Select a country</option><option value="Australia" selected>Australia</option></select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    <input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($ecew)) {echo htmlspecialchars($ecew); } ?>" name="ecew" class="required" id="mce-ecew" placeholder="EC or EW Number" required>
</div>
    <table id="mainform">
            <tr style="display: none;">
                            <th>
                                <label for="address">Address</label>
                            </th>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
                                <p>Humans (and frogs): please leave this field blank.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
        </table>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_f07378b089dcb03e4f7d873e9_c95eea1049" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Send" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="submit"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->

            <?php } ?>

   </section>

        </div>

    </div>

    <P></P>






</div>

</div>
</section>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

      $(".js__p_start, .js__p_another_start").simplePopup();

    });

</script>







      </div>

      <a name="electrician_forum">
      <iframe src="http://www.vestedutility.com.au/forum/" scrolling="no" ></iframe >

     </a> 


</body> 

<?php
 include('inc/footer.php');
 ?>
```

Comment: What is not working?? sending email??

Comment: when you hit send it loads the page again with showing half the table, if i remove a table it works fine?

Comment: at some places you are using `specialcharacter()`` and at some places you are using `htmlspecialchars()` is that intentional?

Comment: no they should be the same thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body>
  <form name="mailinglist" method="post">   
   <input type="text" name="email" />   
   <input type="submit" name="mailing-submit" value="Join Our Mailing 
    List" />     
  </form>     
 <form name="contactus" method="post">    
  <input type="text" name="email" />     
  <input type="text" name="subjet" />    
  <textarea name="message"></textarea>     
  <input type="submit" name="contact-submit" value="Send Email" />     
 </form>
<?php    
  if (!empty($_POST['mailing-submit']))    
   {
   //do something here;   
   }

  if (!empty($_POST['contact-submit'])) 
   {  
   //do something here;  
   }  
 ?>
 </body>
```